# Run all tests except for a JUnit Category in IntelliJ

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit

I pretty much only use JUnit Categories for non-unit tests that I don't want to run as part of the test suite. In NUnit I could use Explicit, but the only thing I've found comparable in JUnit is a Category. In gradle, it's simple to exclude a Category, but I can't figure out how to do this with IntelliJ's test runner. I see how to run tests that belong to a Category, but not how to exclude them.

Comment: I don't think IntelliJ's built-in test runner is intelligent enough to handle this by itself.  Ever consider delegating that action to Gradle instead?

Comment: When I need to do this, it's specifically to not use gradle, e.g. troubleshooting, debugging

Comment: For example, there are bugs that manifest as the gradle test runner either failing silently or hanging indefinitely. It's much easier to pin point the problem with a GUI

Comment: You can specify a category in the debug configuration for a test: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-junit.html

However, it looks like there is no way to exclude a category.

Comment: It's work in progress: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-153780 . You can upvote the issue to make it a bit higher priority.

Comment: @Pieter De Bie thanks, I'm one of the participants in the comments. I've switched to always using Gradle to run tests, which supports the scenario via custom test tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time has passed since I asked this question, and in that time the Gradle test runner has become the default (at least for me). So though the built-in runner may not have this functionality, you can easily create a gradle task that excludes categories or tags:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        excludeTags 'integrationTest'
        excludeTags 'endToEndTest'
        excludeTags 'testDriver'
    }
    options {
        exclude '**/*Integration*'
        exclude 'integrationTest'
        exclude 'endToEndTest'
        exclude 'testDriver'
    }

}
```

[image]